# SASL_SSL and SSL listener co-existing in same Kafka Cluster

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, sasl

I am trying to migrate from SSL Kafka listener to SASL_SSL Kafka listener without disturbing ongoing traffic on SSL listener/port. Is there any way to do this on Kafka version 1.1.1?